# Trying to make an app that adds 2 numbers but it does not work

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio 2017. I have experience in Python, but app development with C# and XAML is completely new to me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace FirstApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Calculate
        {
            Double Num1;
            Double Num2;
            Answer = (Num1 + Num2).ToString();
        }
    }
}

<FlexLayout>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Num1}"></Entry>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Num2}"></Entry>
    <Button Text="Go" Clicked="Calculate"></Button>
    <Label Text="{Binding Answer}"></Label>
</FlexLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing things up, your XAML is Binding to properties but you don't have a ViewModel that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to bind to. Also, your `Calculate` method that is used as a `Clicked` event handler does not receive the parameters of the EventHandler. If you want to go MVVM, you'll also want to ditch event handling for [Commands](https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/) or [Behaviors](https://blog.xamarin.com/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/), but that's another topic.

Here's how to use a ViewModel that Implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and use the `Calculate` method as a `Clicked` event handler.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void Calculate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel viewModel = BindingContext as ViewModel;
        viewModel.Answer = viewModel.Num1 + viewModel.Num2;
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double _num1;
    public double Num1
    {
        get { return _num1; }
        set
        {
            if (_num1 == value)
                return;

            _num1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Num1));
        }
    }

    private double _num2;
    public double Num2
    {
        get { return _num2; }
        set
        {
            if (_num2 == value)
                return;

            _num2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Num2));
        }
    }

    private double _answer;
    public double Answer
    {
        get { return _answer; }
        set
        {
            if (_answer == value)
                return;

            _answer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Answer));
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
}
```